# Segmentation fault issues when creating a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

Ill start out with giving all the code I think is relevant. Basically a Binary Search Tree was already defined that worked and we need to add a parent node functionality. I have done this but I keep getting segmentation faults.

```
template <class TKey>
class bst {
  private:
    struct node {
      node() { key=TKey(); link[0]=link[1]=NULL; parent=NULL; }
      operator TKey () { return key; }
      void print();

      TKey key;
      node *link[2];
      node *parent;
    };

  public:
    class iterator {
    public:
    private:
      friend class bst<TKey>;
      node *p;
    };
    node *prev_node;
    iterator begin() { }
    iterator end() { }

    bst() { Troot=NULL; }
    ~bst() { clear(Troot); }

    bool empty() { return Troot==NULL; }
    void clear() { clear(Troot); Troot=NULL; }

    void erase(TKey &key);
    void insert(TKey &key);

    void print_inorder() { print_inorder(Troot); }
    void print_bylevel();

  private:
    void clear(node *);

    node *minmax_key(node *, int);
    node *erase(node *, TKey &);
    node *insert(node *, TKey &);

    void print_inorder(node *);

    node *Troot;
};
```

Thats the Class Definition.

```
template <class TKey>
void bst<TKey>::insert(TKey &key)
{
    Troot = insert(Troot, key);
}

template <class TKey>
class bst<TKey>::node *bst<TKey>::insert(node *T, TKey &key)
{

        cout << "insert1" << endl;
    if (T == NULL) {

      T = new node;
      T->key = key;
      if (prev_node != NULL)
          T->parent = prev_node;
      cout << T->parent->key;
    } else if (T->key == key) {
      cout << "key " << key << " already in tree" << endl;
    } else {
        prev_node = T;
        int dir = T->key < key;
        T->link[dir] = insert(T->link[dir], key);
    }

    return T;
}
```

These are the insert functions. Im guessing I am doing something out of order because I am still really rusty with recursion. When I run the test program that uses the tree it outputs the inser1 line but then gives a seg fault. So i know it is messing up on the first insert. any help? If you need to see the rest of the code I can put it up but itll be a lot of stuff that isnt actually relevent to the changes Ive made.

Comment: Why not use a debugger like gdb or lldb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking the segfault is on this line

cout << T->parent->key;

If T->parent is null, which it is if T is the newly created root (ie if prev_node == NULL), then you can't access the 'key' of a NULL value.

NOTE: Be aware that I have only skimmed your code, so this is only the first thing I have come across, there could be other bugs.

EDIT:
What do you mean by "I am still having problems", what problems are you having?

It probably isn't how I would implement a BST insert but I can't see anything jumping out saying it is wrong.

How I would implement it is rather than having a global variable prev_node, I would probably change your code like so:

```
template <class TKey>
void bst<TKey>::insert(TKey &key)
{
    // Note that I have an initial prev_node of NULL
    Troot = insert(Troot, key, NULL);
}

// Note the extra function parameter
template <class TKey>
class bst<TKey>::node *bst<TKey>::insert(node *T, TKey &key, node *prev_node)
{

    cout << "insert1" << endl;
    if (T == NULL) {

      T = new node;
      T->key = key;
      // I have a habit of always using braces, so that it is easier to read.
      // This would have helped you with your initial problem.
      if (prev_node != NULL) {
          T->parent = prev_node;
      }
      //cout << T->parent->key;
    } else if (T->key == key) {
      cout << "key " << key << " already in tree" << endl;
    } else {
        int dir = T->key < key;
        T->link[dir] = insert(T->link[dir], key, T); // Note diff here
    }

    return T;
}
```

Unless you are using prev_node somewhere else.

But this shouldn't change how the insert works, unless in your implementation:

1. prev_node is not null initially for some reason (which would be the case on successive inserts, unless you are resetting it somewhere else).
2. something is changing prev_node while you are using it (think thread-safety)

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes I feel dumb. Something I put in to check caused the error

Comment: Sorry I am still having problems. Can you see anything wrong with how I am actually implementing the parent node?